# Adding a range of cells to one cell based on a condition

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a sheet in Ms Excel with Loan details, where the loan status is either 'Paid' or 'Unpaid'. For every row, I want to add the **amount** value to cell C18 if the corresponding cell in **status** column reads "Unpaid".

eg. for row 10,

```
=IF(J10 ="Unpaid", $C$18+G10, $C$18+0)  **{This does not work}**
```

How can I achieve this so as to use the formula for a couple of rows?

Comment: plz provide some sample data with expected results. I cannot see, why your provided function won't work.

Comment: Your tags are a bit confusing, are you using Google Sheets or Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess from what you're saying is that you want to add column G only when the corresponding value in column J = "Unpaid".

If so, the formula you put in C18 is `=SUMIFS(G:G,J:J,"Unpaid")` or `=SUMIFS(G10:G,J10:J,"Unpaid")` if you want to start the sum at row 10.

Answer (score 1):

You might try ...

```
=C$18+(J10="Unpaid")*G10
```

This formula will add C18 to G10, but only if J10 says "Unpaid", otherwise, it will just add C18 to 0.

It can be "dragged down" for the other rows, and the '$' on C$18 will keep that cell fixed while the references for J and G will correspond to the row that the formula is in.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add to $c$10, only to a new column, lets say called 'balance'. There (column k) would be the formula =$k9+if($j10="Unpaid",$g10,0)

Comment: Thank you.. that works when a single row is involved. How do I implement for the check to happen to a range??  I tried  **=C18 + IF(J10:J14="Unpaid", G10:G14,0)** but  I get "An array value could not be found." Error

Comment: wrapping aound the arrayformula-function could help, but im very bad using it. copy-paste my proposed formula could help in analytics too, like tendency calculation 

Answer (score 0):

in Google Sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(J10:J50="Unpaid"; C18+G10:G50; C18))
```